# Unresolvable dependency resolving in Laravel Repository

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection, repository

I'm having an "Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #1 [  $mainPage ]]" error after trying to manage dependency injection in my Repository. I've already managed to build my controller, repository, interface and service provider. Is something missing here? I'm I doing something wrong in my logic?

**Home Controller**

```
use Repositories\MainPageRepository;

class HomeController extends BaseController {

protected $cPage, $mainPage;

public function __construct(MainPageRepository $cPage, $mainPage)
{
    $this->cPage = $cPage;
    $this->mainPage = $mainPage;
}

public function getPages($lang, $slug)
{

    $cPage = $this->cPage->getCurrentPage($lang, $slug);

    $mainPages = $this->mainPage->getAllMainPages($cPage);

    $allPages = $this->getAllPages($mainPages);

    return View::make('index')
    ->with('cPage', $cPage)
    ->with('mainPages', $mainPages)
    ->with('allPages', $allPages);
}

private function getAllPages($pages) 
{
    $allPages = array();

    foreach ($pages as $page) {

          //...

    }
    return $allPages;
}
```

**MainPageInterface**

```
namespace Repositories;

interface MainPageInterface {

  public function getCurrentPage($lang, $slug);

  public function getAllMainPages($cPage);
}
```

**MainPageRepository**

```
namespace Repositories;

use Page;

class MainPageRepository implements MainPageInterface{

  public function getCurrentPage($lang, $slug)
  {
    $cPage = Page::join('langs', 'langs.id', '=', 'pages.lang_parent_id')
                ->where('slug', '=', $slug)
                ->where('code', '=', $lang)
                ->first();

    return $cPage;
  }

  public function getAllMainPages($cPage)
  {
    $mainPage = Page::join('langs', 'langs.id', '=', 'pages.lang_parent_id')
            ->where('parent_id', null)
            ->get();

    return $mainPage;
  } 
}
```

**MainPageServiceProvider**

```
namespace Repositories;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class MainPageServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

  public function register()
  {
    $this->app->bind('MainPageInterface', 'MainPageRepository');
  }
}
```

**Implemented changes after @Matt Burrows answer:**
The problem still persists
**Controller**

```
use Repositories\MainPageInterface;

class HomeController extends BaseController {

protected $cPage, $mainPage;

public function __construct(MainPageInterface $cPage, $mainPage)
{
    $this->cPage = $cPage;
    $this->mainPage = $mainPage;
}
```

**Service Provider**

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind('Repositories\MainPageInterface', 'Repositories\MainPageRepository');
}
```

---

Ok, so I finally managed to get over this by splitting the two functions in my repository into 2 seperate repositories. That did the trick. I'll accept @Matts answer as correct in any case, since he spotted some important mistakes nonetheless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
$this->app->bind('MainPageInterface', 'MainPageRepository');
```

to

```
$this->app->bind('Repositories\MainPageInterface', 'Repositories\MainPageRepository');
```

Within your service provider.

Also change

```
use Repositories\MainPageRepository;
```

to

```
use Repositories\MainPageInterface;
```

and change

```
public function __construct(MainPageRepository $cPage, $mainPage)
```

to

```
public function __construct(MainPageInterface $cPage, $mainPage)
```

And it should work.

Remember to register your service provider within app.php if you have not done so already.

This can be done by adding the class path to the array of providers like so;

```
'providers' => array(
    //...
    'Repositories\MainPageServiceProvider'
)
```

Be sure to `composer dump-autoload` too

For the problem of `Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #1 [ $mainPage ]]` this is because IoC container does not know what type of object $mainPage is. Type cast the object and you will get what you want.

This can be done like so;

```
use Path\To\A\Object;

...

__construct(MainPageRepository $cPage, Object $mainPage)
```

Comment: Hi Matt, I've checked your answer and after trying those changes I keep getting the same unresolvable dependency error I have in the original question.. =/

Comment: And as I told @Fire, the path for the provider is already implemented, and running the autoload led to no changes either.

Comment: @RuiSilva updated bottom of answer. As we dont particularly know the type of $mainPage we cannot give you the answer you want. But the IoC container is having problems resolving the object for you.

Comment: Do you want me to provide some more info about anything? I'm not even sure were that $mainPage variable is broken because the repository was retrieving the right array from the database before I tried to implement the injections of $lang and $slug.

Comment: Im not on about $lang or $slug in your controller the second parameter is $mainPage, the IoC container resolves objects via their paths or by type, you have given very little information leading to this error for the variable.

Answer (score 0):

You should be injecting `MainPageInterface` into your controller not `MainPageRepository`, that's the point of binding in the service provider.

Comment: I've already tried that, but I get "Target [Repositories\MainPageInterface] is not instantiable".

Comment: Did you register the service provider in app/config/app.php?

Comment: Hi Fire, I actually did add this line to it 'Repositories\MainPageServiceProvider'

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
use Repositories\MainPageRepository;
```

it should be

```
use Repositories\MainPageInterface;
```

Comment: If I just change that I'll get a non existing class error. But as I answered to Fire, I've already tried to inject the interface without any luck.

Comment: check @Matt Burrows answer. that's the whole version. didn't look at the serviceprovider file in your code so my code is half the part. apply his solution.

Comment: I've already checked @Matts Burrows answer and after it I keep quetting the same unresolvable dependency error I have in the original question.. =/

Comment: Matt Burrows answer __should__ work. you have error in modification. post the relevent part from each file and edit your question. (don't remove the old question, just add the modifications in a new part).